# Why the_title() function doesn't work, when I use it inside the title tag in the header.php file?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Why `the_title()` function doesn't work, when I use it inside the title tag in the header.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress, you should use the [Title Tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag) feature.

1. Delete `<title>` tag
2. Call `wp_head();` in `<head>` tag
3. Add `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` in functions.php